# CheckListBox - Selecionar apenas um registro

Tags: delphi

O `TCheckListBox` permite selecionar diversos itens, mas diferente de alguns componentes vamos dizer "parentes dele" possui a propriedade *Booleana* **MultiSelect**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma função ou procedimento para que ele permita apenas 1 item selecionado?

Comment: Utilize TRadioGroup

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound então amigo. Eu preciso usar esse maldito. Vou fazer uns testes com o RG...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Compartilhando com os Colegas de Delphi!**

Após varias pesquisas, a única opção foi implementar o evento `OnClickCheck` do componente, acredito que esta seja a única opção:

```
procedure MultiSelect;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  with Seu_CheckListBox do
  begin
    if (Checked[ItemIndex]) then
    begin
      Items.BeginUpdate;
      for i := 0 to Pred(Items.Count) do
      begin
        if (i <> ItemIndex) then
          Checked[i] := False;
      end;
      Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Ficou 100% sem atrapalhar o Funcionamento do componente!

Caso precise ativar basta passar para o evento `OnClickCheck` a procedue `MultiSelect`, para remover passe `Nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Não, o checklistbox já foi desenvolvido para que seja selecionado mais de um registro.

Se vc precisa trabalhar com este componente e quer que somente um registro seja selecionado pode realizar uma validação da seguinte forma

```
total := 0;
for i := 0 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin

       if CheckListBox1.Checked[i] then    // se o registro estiver marcado...
          inc(total);

    end;

if total > 1 then
   ShowMessage('Atenção somente 1 registro pode ser selecionado.');
```

Comment: obrigado pela força na resolução, eu já usava algo semelhante, o chato era sempre enviar essa notificação! Segue minha resposta com solução perfeita para isso!